Three.js infinite scroll
I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll to this web page I'm building.
Basically what I want to do is as soon as one element (the card/box) is out of the camera view, it gets moved at the end of the line of boxes, and then the next and so on.
But right now the problem I have is that the swapping of the boxes happens recursively (I believe) and never stops until the animation stops or something to that extent.
Thank you to everyone who can help me with this!
Here's the JS:
import { TextureLoader } from 'three';
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import gsap from 'gsap';

const canvas = document.querySelector('.webgl');
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

const boxGroup = new THREE.Group();
scene.add(boxGroup);

const zoom = 500;
const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
};

const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
  -sizes.width / zoom,
  sizes.width / zoom,
  sizes.height / zoom,
  -sizes.height / zoom,
  -100,
  1000
);

camera.position.set(2, 2, 5);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 2);
scene.add(ambientLight);

let currentlyHoveredBox = null;
const boxes = [];
const boxSpacing = 1;

function createBox(texture, positionZ) {
  const aspect = texture.image.width / texture.image.height;
  const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1 * aspect, 1, 0.02);
  const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: texture,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.9
  });
  texture.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
  const box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
  box.position.set(0, 0, -positionZ);
  boxGroup.add(box);

  const hoverGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1.05 * aspect, 1.5, 0.05);
  const hoverMesh = new THREE.Mesh(hoverGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ visible: false }));
  hoverMesh.position.copy(box.position);
  boxGroup.add(hoverMesh);

  hoverMesh.userData.isHoverMesh = true;
  hoverMesh.userData.parentBox = box;
  box.userData.hoverMesh = hoverMesh;
  box.userData.hover = {
    enter: () => {
      if (currentlyHoveredBox !== box) {
        if (currentlyHoveredBox) {
          currentlyHoveredBox.userData.hover.leave();
        }
        currentlyHoveredBox = box;
        gsap.to(box.position, {
          y: 0.2,
          duration: 0.3,
          ease: "power2.out"
        });
      }
    },
    leave: () => {
      if (currentlyHoveredBox === box) {
        currentlyHoveredBox = null;
        gsap.to(box.position, {
          y: 0,
          duration: 0.3,
          ease: "power2.out"
        });
      }
    }
  };
  boxes.push(box);
}

const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const imageUrls = [
  'proj/1.jpg',
  'proj/2.jpg',
  'proj/3.jpg',
  'proj/4.jpg',
  'proj/5.jpg',
  'proj/6.jpg',
  'proj/7.jpg',
  'proj/8.jpg',
  'proj/9.jpg',
  'proj/10.jpg',
];
imageUrls.forEach((url, index) => {
  loader.load(url, (texture) => {
    createBox(texture, index * boxSpacing);
  });
});

const totalScrollDistance = (imageUrls.length) * boxSpacing;

function onMouseWheel(event) {
  const scrollSpeed = 0.1;
  let targetZ = boxGroup.position.z + event.deltaY * scrollSpeed;

  gsap.to(boxGroup.position, {
    z: targetZ,
    duration: 0.6,
    ease: "power2.out",
    onUpdate: updateBoxPositions
  });
}

function updateBoxPositions() {
  const threshold = totalScrollDistance * 0.5;
  boxes.forEach((box) => {
    let newZ = box.position.z + boxGroup.position.z;
    if (newZ > threshold) {
      newZ -= totalScrollDistance;
    } else if (newZ < -threshold) {
      newZ += totalScrollDistance;
    }
    box.position.z = newZ;
    box.userData.hoverMesh.position.z = newZ;
  });
  // boxGroup.position.z = 0;
}

window.addEventListener('wheel', onMouseWheel);

const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function updateRaycaster() {
  raycaster.far = Math.abs(boxGroup.position.z) + 10;
}

function handleHover() {
  const hoverMeshes = boxGroup.children.filter(child => child.userData.isHoverMesh);
  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(hoverMeshes);
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    const hoveredBox = intersects[0].object.userData.parentBox;
    hoveredBox.userData.hover.enter();
  } else if (currentlyHoveredBox) {
    currentlyHoveredBox.userData.hover.leave();
  }
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
  sizes.height = window.innerHeight;

  camera.left = -sizes.width / zoom;
  camera.right = sizes.width / zoom;
  camera.top = sizes.height / zoom;
  camera.bottom = -sizes.height / zoom;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
});

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  updateRaycaster();
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  handleHover();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();


I tried creating some logic to make it work but to no avail, it still does that glitch

The first step in solving things like this is to simplify the problem. Reduce your code and just produce a simple single cube mesh that travels across your screen. Learn how to detect when it has moved outside the viewport, so you can move it back to the other side. You shouldn't need a perpetual counter (unless that's useful to you somehow), just a timer to occasionally keep the box moving forward. You may even find a clever way to use the animate loop for this purpose.
